# Metadata won't show in U1 Music for Android

Tags: ubuntu-one, music, android

I can't get the metadata to display on U1 Music for Android. All I get is "unknown artist" and "unknown album". Everything shows up in Banshee. The files live in my purchased music folder and were purchased within the last few weeks.

- The phone is a Samsung Admire, SCH-R720.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).